# Get-Content error when passing variable as path - Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have the following script.

```
#Script publicador
$carpetas = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path  C:\Publicaout | Sort-Object {[int]($_ -replace '(\d+).*', '$1')} | Format-Wide -Column 1 -Property Name | Out-String

foreach ($line in $carpetas.Split([string[]]"`r`n", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
  $destino = Get-Content c:\Publicaout\$line\Destino.txt
  echo $destino
  #Copy-Item -Path C:\Publicaout\$line -Recurse -Destination C:\temp\ -ToSession $session -Force 
  #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $destino -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'c:\temp\$Using:line\publicador.bat'"}
  #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $destino -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item \\$Using:destino\c$\temp\$Using:line -Recurse -Force}

}
```

What it does, first it sorts by numerical order subfolders on a folder called `Publicaout` in `C:`, then I get the list of those subfolders in order, and I use for each to use each element of the list as a parameter, for each one of those folders, I copy it to a remote server, and then I run a script which is located within that copied folder, after that, i delete that folder so i do not leave any leftovers.

So far so good, but now, within each folder there's a text file that contains the destination server that each specific folder must be copied to. So, I believed that adding a `Get-Content` + path to the file, using the `$line` variable that contains the subfolder name would be enough, but each time I run the script i get this error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Publicaout\3000\Destino.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\elmarichaladmin\Documents\publicador.ps1:18 char:14
+   $destino = Get-Content c:\Publicaout\$line\Destino.txt
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Publicaout\3...   \Destino.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

This happens with each folder, i have 5 folders, named 1, 99,654,3000, 65404. Its really weird because the `Copy` command works perfect, but Get-Content does not.

Any ideas? I know that the errors shows an empty line, but as you can see I get rid of each empty line when i run the string split.

Comment: remove the `Format-*` & `Out-String` cmdlets from your pipeline. the 1st **_destroy_** your objects and wrap them in formatting code. the 2nd converts your objects to STRINGS that lack any context.

Comment: `$destino_path = "c:\Publicaout\" + $line + "Destino.txt"`
`$destino = Get-Content $destino_path` I think it's a problem with how you contructed your path, try this. If it works I'll post as answer to be accepted.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: I found a workaround using this: $recorte = $line -split ' ' | where {$_.Trim() -ne ''}
  
  $destino = gc c:\Publicaout\$recorte\Destino.txt       And now it works as espected. Anyway i think this script is not optimized.  My path is correct, the problem was that when i add the parameter $line into the Get-Content it adds a lot of blank spaces. I got rid of them using the solution above.

Comment: I will try Lee_Dailey solution and I will tell you the results.